# Decline Jenkins Job if PR has Merge Conflict

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to decline Jenkins Job for PR if a merge conflict is present. 
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pre-tested integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pretested-integration/) to verify your commits and make a decision whether to process with Jenkins job or discard it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I didn't want to install any plugin I got a solution where I can distinguish whether there is a merge conflict in that particular pull request or not. There is a git parameter **${GITHUB_PR_COND_REF}** which we can make use of